# MVC server side JSON retrieval

Tags: c#, asp.net, json, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

We have to modify one of our projects due to changes in security implemented by our data provider. Currently, the system was open and we implemented ajax data retrieval on client side directly from the source, however we were notified by the provider that they will be implementing an IP lockdown and told us we need to implement some form of proxy. We deliberated for a bit and decided we should try another route and instead load and cache their data at our IIS server and give it to our customers via ajax calls to our own server. It would also allow our BUs to do some aggregate analysis of the data.

That being said, what is the best/recommended way to issue JSON http/s requests from controller code to an external source and deserialize that JSON for server side processing? If its important, the format of ajax documents is static, it wont change (meaning, we could create model classes for it if needed).

Comment: Awesome, a close and downvote instead of an answer. Thanks.  If I knew it I wouldn't ask it, asp.net is not really my primary technology. So, can we now get off the high horse, dispense with the elitism and offer an answer? I'll be much obliged.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I hope this help. I used something like to make youtube api calls and turn the JSON response to my own model.

```
        "{result: [{ name: \"Joe Doe\", age: 23 }]}"; // json format coming back from external url

        using (var client = new HttpClient())
        {
            var response = await client.GetAsync("URL");

            response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();

            var content = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

            dynamic values = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<dynamic>(content);

            var people = new List<Person>();

            foreach (var item in values.result)
            {
                var person = new Person
                {
                    Name = item.name,
                    Age = item.age
                };

                people.Add(person);
            }

            return people;
```

The Person Model:

```
    public class Person
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public int Age { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: Perfect, exactly what I need, async approach included. Thanks.